# Task Scheduler - Error Message "The Last day of the month option is supported only on Windows Vista or later"

Tags: windows-7, task-scheduler

Video Reproduce:
http://tinypic.com/r/2ni4fhc/8

I am running on **Windows 7 Pro SP1 64-Bit**

[image: Windows 7 Pro SP1 64-bit]

Using Windows Task Scheduler - I edit an existing task.

Trigger

Select Monthly

and the Days I selected Last.

[image: Trigger for last day of the month]

When I apply the task it shows **Error Message** "The Last day of the month option is supported only on Windows Vista or later"

[image: Error Message]

But I am using Windows Vista later which is Windows 7

How to fix this bug?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Window 7 Home Premium 64 bit SP1.

Comment: means your windows 7 home premium able to create it with Last parameter?

Comment: Yes, I used exactly the same settings as in your image to create a test task.

Comment: OK, sorry my problem. I am not create it, I am actually update it from previous task.

Comment: I added video how I reproduce

Comment: My only suggestion is to create the task from scratch, rather than updating an existing one ... I have no other ideas :/

Comment: Okay, This task schedule is generate by third party. However, that software can't select Last Day. I just copy and paste all the parameter from that current task to new task. Thanks @DavidPostill

Comment: @DavidPostill I finally found the answer ;D Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I finally I know the answer.

It is because of the Configure for is selected to **Windows Server 2003, Windows XP or Windows 2000**

Once you updated to other 2, I am able to use the **LAST day** selection.

[image: Task Scheduler - Configure for Windows XP - that's made the error message]